# ListPlot of two columns of a Dataset with respect to one another

Tags: plotting, dataset

Say I have some data in two columns of a set called `table` which are labelled C1 and C2, I can do the following:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Normal@table[All, "C1"], Normal@table[All, "C2"]}]]
```

Is there a way to do it by instead doing something like this ?

```
table[All, ListPlot@{"C1", "C2"}]
```

which doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Here is a working example of what I would like it to look like, only without having to export the elements of the table using `Normal`.

[image: example]

Comment: could you provide some arbitrary dataset, or an example of how you'd want it to look in the end?

Comment: you're right, it's probably simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick example:

```
pd = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];

pd[ListPlot, {"Mass", "Radius"}]
```

[image: mass vs. radius plot for planets]

Comment: I had no idea, it was this simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time with `Association`s (which I often use to store complicated engineering data sets), but `Dataset` adds a twist that can be handled with `Normal` or `Query`

```
ds = Dataset@Association@{"a" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "b" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}^2};

ListPlot[Transpose[{#a, #b}] &@Normal@ds]
```

or

```
ListPlot[Query[Transpose[{#a, #b}] &]@ds]
```

I think `Query` is tidier and more robust because it works with both `Association` and `Dataset`.

Comment: Very handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module[
 {x, y},
 x = Range[0, 10];
 y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 11];

 ListPlot @ Transpose[{x, y}]
]
```

Comment: That does not make use of datasets. I am familiar with the usual ListPlot for lists. I am trying to use datasets here though

Comment: So, you load a file. The file contains - `{x,y}` coordinate pair. What prevents you from just loading the files and doing `ListPlot @ table[[ All, {1,2} ]]`

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
ds = Table[{x, x^2, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 2, 0.1}]
```

Dataset:

```
    ds = Dataset@
  Table[AssociationThread[{"x", "square", "root"} -> ds[[i]]], {i, 
    Length@ds}]
```

then:

```
ListPlot[(Normal@Values@(ds[All, {"square", "root"}]))\[Transpose]]
```

Comment: this is not what I need. It plots two separate listplots on the same graph. I need to plot one column against the other

Comment: @jrekier: o.k. I did not understand your question right.